# user gets logged out on page refresh in php

Tags: php, login-script

WebPage.php

```
<?php
    session_start();    
    include 'functions.php';
?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Ecommerce</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Styling.css">

</head>
<body onLoad="CheckLogin()">

<script>

  function CheckLogin(){
      var loggedIn = "<?php
        if(isset($_SESSION['email'])){
            echo 'true';
        }else{
            echo 'false';
        }   ?>"

      var logout_Form = document.getElementById("logout_Form"); 
      var login_Form = document.getElementById("login_Form"); 

      if(loggedIn == "true"){
          login_Form.style.display="none";
          logout_Form.style.display = "show";
      }else{
          logout_Form.style.display="none";
          login_Form.style.display = "show";
      }
  }

  function LogOut(){
      <?php  
        session_destroy();

      ?>
      window.open('WebPage.php', '_self');
  }

  function Login()
  {
    var modal = document.getElementById('loginModal');

    var btn = document.getElementById("login");

    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

    modal.style.display = "block";


    span.onclick = function() {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }

    window.onclick = function(event) {
        if (event.target == modal) {
            modal.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
  }

  function SignUp()
  {
        var modal = document.getElementById('signModal');

        var btn = document.getElementById("signUp");

        var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close2")[0];

        modal.style.display = "block";

        span.onclick = function() {
            modal.style.display = "none";
        }

        window.onclick = function(event) {
            if (event.target == modal) {
                modal.style.display = "none";
            }
        }
  }
</script>

<div style = "background:cyan">
<font color="green"><h1><center>WELCOME</center></h1></font>
    <div>

<!--Logo and Search Box-->  
        <form method="GET" action = "results.php">
            <a href="WebPage.php"><img src = "ball.png" alt = "Logo of Website" height = "100px" width = "100px"></a>
            <input type = "text" name = "user_query" placeholder="Search" size="50px" style="overflow:hidden">
            <button type="Submit" name="search">Search</button>
        </form>

<!--LOGIN-->    
    <div id="login_Form">   
    <button id = "login" onclick="Login()">Login</button>
    <button id="signUp" onclick="SignUp()">Sign Up</button> 

    <div id="loginModal" class="loginModal">

    <!-- Modal content -->
    <div class="login-content">
            <span class="close">&times;</span>
            <p><h2>Login</h2>
        <form name="login" method="POST" id="login" action="loginCheckUser.php">
            <label><b>E-Mail ID: </b></label>
            <input type="email" name="email" required>
            <br><br>
            <label><b>Password: </b></label>
            <input type="password" name="pass" required>
            <br><br>
            <button type="submit" id="submit" name="submit">Login</button>
            <a href="loginCheckSell.php"><input type="button" id="sellerLogin" value="Login as Seller"></a>
            <br><br>
            <input type="checkbox" checked>Remember Me
        </form></p>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div id="signModal" class="signModal">

        <!-- Modal content -->
        <div class="signUp-content">
            <span class="close2">&times;</span>
            <p><h2>Sign Up</h2>
        <form name="signup" action="register.php" method="POST" id="signup">
            <label><b>Name: </b></label>
            <input type="text" name="name" required>
            <br><br>
            <label><b>E-Mail ID: </b></label>
            <input type="email" name="email" required>
            <br><br>
            <label><b>Password: </b></label>
            <input type="password" name="pass" required>
            <br><br>
            <label><b>Confirm Password: </b></label>
            <input type="password" name="con_pass" required>
            <br><br>
            <label><b>Mobile No: </b></label>
            <input type="tel" id="phoneno" name="phone" required>
            <br><br>
            <button type="submit" id="submit" name="submit">Register</button>
            <a href="regSell.php"><button type="submit" id="subSell" name="subSell">Register as Seller</button></a>
        </form></p>
        </div>


    </div>
    </div>

    <div id="logout_Form">
        <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="dropbtn"> <?php 
                        echo "Hi ";
                        if(isset($_SESSION['email'])){
                            echo getName($_SESSION['email']);
                        }
            ?></button>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="myAccount.php?account=a&personal=p">Account</a>
                <a href="myAccount.php?orders">Orders</a>

            </div>
        </div>
        <button name="logout" id="logout" onclick="LogOut()">Log Out</button>
    </div>

    </div>


    </div>  
<!--Categories-->   
    <div>
        <ul id="searchMenu">
            <li>
                <a href="#" title="Electronics">Electronics</a></li>
            &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp
            <li>
                <a href="#" title="Appliances">Appliances</a></li>
            &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp 
            <li>
                <a href="#" title = "Men">Men</a></li>
            &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp
            <li>
                <a href="#" title="Women">Women</a></li>

        </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="content_area">

    <?php cart();?>
        <div id="shopping_cart">
            <span style = "float: right; font-size: 18px; padding: 5px, line-height:40px;">
                Welcome <b style="color:yellow">Shopping Cart: </b>Total Items: <?php total_items();?> - Total Price: <?php total_price();?><a href="cart.php">Go to Cart</a>

            </span>
        </div>

        <?php
            $ip = getIp();
        ?>
        <div id="products_box">
            <?php

                get_pro();
                getCatPro();
                getBrandPro();
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<!--Company Info-->
    <div>
        <ul id="CompInfo" >
            <li style="background-color:red"><a href="WebPage.php">Home</a></li>
            <li style="background-color:red"><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
            <li style="background-color:red"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>

        </ul>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

The modal contents gives a pop up window.
As soon as I refresh the page the logout buttons disappears and there are the login buttons. But I want the site to have the same state as it was before refreshing. Only 1 can be there either login form or logout form.

loginCheckUser.php

```
<?php  session_start();?>
<html><head>

</head>
<body>

<script>
        var lat =0 ;
        var lon =0 ;

        function getLocation() {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
        }

        function showPosition(position) {
            document.getElementById("lat").value = position.coords.latitude; 
            document.getElementById("lon").value =  position.coords.longitude;
            document.getElementById("check").value= "true";
            document.getElementById("form").submit();
        }


</script>
<form id="form" method="post">
<input type="hidden" id="lat" name="lat">
<input type="hidden" id="lon" name="lon">
<input type="hidden" id="check" value="">

</form>

<?php

include 'functions.php';

$email =$_POST['email'];
$pass =$_POST['pass'];

if($email && $pass){

$connect = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '','test') or die("Couldn't connect to database");

$ip = getIp();
$query = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email'") or die("NO query");

$numrows = mysqli_num_rows($query);

if($numrows >=1){

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
        $dbemail = $row['email'];
        $dbpass = $row['pass'];
    }

    if($email == $dbemail && md5($pass) == $dbpass){
        echo '<script>
                getLocation();

              </script>';

        $latitude = $_POST['lat'];
        $longitude = $_POST['lon'];

        $check =$_POST['check'];


        if($check=='true'){
            $sql1 = "UPDATE users SET lat  = '$latitude', lon  = '$longitude' where email = '$email'";

            mysqli_query($connect, $sql1);
        }

        $name="";
        $q = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT name FROM users where email = '$email'") or die("cannot get");
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q)){
            $name = $row['name'];
        }

        $_SESSION['email'] = $email;

        header("location: WebPage.php");

    }else{
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Your password is incorrect');</script>";
        header("location: WebPage.php");
    }
}

else{
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('The user Doesn't exist');</script>";
    header("location: WebPage.php");
}

}

?>  </body></html>
```

Comment: `session_start()` should be at the very top, before any HTML is output.

Comment: dont mix js and php so extremly. You can do the login/logot functions also in php. Your code is to mixed and very bad to read.

Comment: @Alex Wiebogen .Sorry for the trouble. But I don't know how to get the latitude and longitude in html. That's why I needed to include both js and php.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the condition here:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
    session_start();    
}
```

The main reason to have `session_start()` is for setting the session. Before that, the `$_SESSION` will be empty and the session never gets set. And make sure, `session_start()` is always at the top, first, as it is similar to `header()` function.

Comment: Sorry but the problem still persists.

Comment: This is the first full page. Do you want the loginCheckUser.php file also?

Comment: @AyushBansal Yea, it will be helpful. Is it there the session gets set right?

Answer (score 0):

You have to start session at beggining of **every** page you are going to use session on.

Change

```
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
    session_start();    
}
```

to

```
session_start();
```

Make `session_start();` is the very first thing called on every page where you are using $_SESSION. Also, make sure no spaces or tabs are before `<?php`

Comment: Sorry. No changes in the output. Still Working the same. Could it be a server problem? I am working on the XAMPP server.

Comment: Have you included the session_start(); like this? `<?php session_start(); ?> <html>
<head>
    <title>Ecommerce</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Styling.css">

</head>
<body onLoad="CheckLogin()">
<?php
    if(!isset($_SESSION)){
            session_start();    `

Comment: @ Ondrej Vrabel . I have updated the code for session_start().

Comment: @AyushBansal where are you setting the SESSION? And the logout is not going to work! You are mixing JavaScript with PHP. The PHP gets executed even without the javascript call (automatic logout). PHP is server-side language, javascript is client-side.

Comment: @ Ondrej Vrabel. I have added the SESSION variables in the loginCheckUser.php. The logOut() is working perfectly fine.

Comment: @ Ondrej Vrabel. Could you please tell me where I can see the Session Variables in Chrome other than Inspect -> Application -> Session Storage. Because it is showing empty to me.

Comment: Ohh, $_SESSION is not sent to browser! Read about PHP session: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp and HTML 5 Session storage https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage